# Cache that only uses the reference of the key object in java (and not hashCode or equals)

Tags: java, caching, reference

I'd have a class that runs some expensive calculations multiple times. I'd like to add a cache for it like:

```
private Map<MyObj, Result> cache = new HashMap<>();

private Result getFoo(MyObj myObj) {
    Result r = cache.get(myObj);
    if (r == null) {
        r = expensiveCalculation(myObj);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Since I know the only way two MyObj-s can be equal is if they're identical (the reference), I don't want the cache to calculate the hashCode() and equals(). Is there a way to have a Map that uses only the reference for hashing?

Or a better way to cache like this?

Comment: You mean something like [IdentityHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html)?

Comment: @ThomasKläger exactly! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please mind that this no optimization. There is no benefit and your code gets more complicated.

> Since I know the only way two MyObj-s can be equal is if they're identical (the reference), I don't want the cache to calculate the hashCode() and equals().

The `hashCode` is always calculated to make the storage in the hash table. 
Before the equals method is called on the key objects it is a common optimization in hash tables implementations to check for identical reference first.